# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_33 to have shape (60, 60, 5) but got array with shape (240, 240, 5)

Tags: python, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding, conv-neural-network, densenet

When I  try to train this model, it generates the error 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_33 to have shape (60, 60, 5) but got array with shape (240, 240, 5)'.
After one-hot encoding, y_train.shape is (4992, 240, 240, 5).
x_train.shape is (4992, 240, 240, 1)

Please help me to solve this error. I am a beginner to deep learning.

```
#My training model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),input_shape=(240,240,1),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) 
model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),padding='same',activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))  
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense((num_classes),  activation='softmax'))#output layer
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, ytrain, validation_data=(x_test, ytest),epochs=10, batch_size=64,
```

verbose=2)